# Twitter Bootstrap. Collapsing child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Let's say we have a thumbnail:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/260x180" />
    <div class="details">
        <h5>Heading</h5>
        <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i></a>
        <a class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="?" href="#"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></a>
        <a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

is it possible to collapse/toggle the parent's paragraph `<p>` using attributes? What should `data-target` look like then?
And also I wanted to ask if it is reasonable to use data-attributes or it is better to use `Twitter` js API?

Answer (score 1):

With regard to whether it's 'better' to use `data-` attributes or the API, unless you have a specific use-case in mind, the question is meaningless. It doesn't matter if you're using the `data-` attributes or using the API, the same thing is achieved - the initialisation and/or configuration of a widget.

Some people don't like using `data-` attributes and therefore 'prefer' using the API, but to the outside observer, the implementer's preference is not applicable. Similarly, non-programmers may find using the `data-` attributes 'easier', but again, to the end user, it makes no difference what the designer finds easier, all they are interested in is the final result - the widget.

I did have a specific use-case recently where I had to use the API - I wanted to show an accordion (collapsible) in the mobile view, but not in the desktop view of an application. If I used the `data-` attributes to initialise and configure the accordion, the desktop view inherited this and built the accordion automatically. In this case it was 'better' to use the API because it meant that I could only initialise the accordion when the screen was less than `768px` in width, avoiding a bunch of script stuff to disable the functionality in the desktop view...

Comment: So is it possible to collapse a paragraph on a certian thumbnail only using data-target by clicking a button inside the thumbnail?

Comment: I don't know for sure, hence why I only answered the second part of the question ;)

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway that was usefull, I was worried that using data atributes provides some performance drawbacks. Now all worries are gone)

Comment: Not as far as I am aware, or have noticed through general use. I suppose you could argue that using the API touches the DOM less (no checking elements for 'data-' attributes), but I would expect the impact of this to be negligible. Unless you're building a page with 500 widgets on, the difference should be imperceptible :)